# Connecting to MacOS file share

Tags: pantheon-files

I have an iMac with an AFP and an SMB file share enabled and Elementary on a laptop. Elementary OS will connect using AFP but I receive a message saying “This Folder is Empty”. Trying to connect via SMB prompts me for a user name, domain, and password. I enter the user name and password correctly but I do not know what to use for the domain.

Any suggestions on how to connect? I am able to connect to the iMac SMB shares from other devices.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the default domain "WORKGROUP" work? What domain do you specify when connecting from other devices?

Comment: I have an AFP share setup on another server (not an iMac) and it works OK although all the content was uploaded from elementary.  Are you logging into the AFP with same name and password as when the content was created?

Comment: I’m able to connect to another AFP (nas device) just fine so I’m thinking it may be something specific to the Mac setup. Re the domain, I have tried numerous options and none seem to work. When connecting from other devices I have not needed to specify a domain.

Comment: I presume the SMB and AFP servers are set up automatically on the MacOS? Hopefully a MacOS user may be able to offer more help, but if you can find the smb.conf file on the MacOS it should tell you what the domain name is (defaults to WORKGROUP if not specified).  There are some command line tools or dedicated GUI Samba clients you could try and used to connect to the MacOS smb share and get more info about it.

Comment: Which version of ElementaryOS and FIles are you using?